# The system is running in low-graphics mode

Tags: 12.04, login, display-manager

I've an HP personal computer with an integrated graphics card. It worked fine until yesterday.

Now when I try to switch to gdm it just boots up with my usual background and a computer icon in the middle of the screen. I can't do anything; I can't click it and can't log in.

I get the error message:

```
The system is running in low-graphics mode
```

I have tried the solution in [How to fix "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

I have tried:
1. `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`
2. Verified greeter-session=pantheon-greeter
3. Have tried switching to GDM
4. Have checked I have enough free disk space
5. Installing a new Intel driver from X-Swat repository
6. Reinstalling xserver-xorg

What else can I try?

Comment: There are several solutions mentioned in the link you provided; did you change the pantheon-greeter back to the unity-greeter in the lightdm.conf?

Comment: It's probably because lack off proper graphics driver, can you post your result of "lspci -nn" and also attach /var/log/xorg.0.log ? if it's nvidia optimus laptop you could also try to remove nvidia-current driver too.

Comment: Have you seen:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error  ?

Comment: You are probably running out of disk space. Paste the result of du -sh command executed in / directory.